# React Router 4, How do I get a valid match url with route render or with withRouter?

Tags: react-router-v4

The match object I receive using either the render property on the Route component  or using an HOC from withRouter always produces a match object that is wrong. The location object is correct. The match url property is always '/'

Here is a code pen that shows the problem [React Router 4 match woes](https://codepen.io/stocksp/pen/jmoxoo?editors=1111)

```
const { render } = ReactDOM

    const {
      HashRouter,
      Route,
      Link
    } = ReactRouterDOM

    const App = () => (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <AddressBar/>

          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
          </ul>

          <hr/>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
          <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    )

    const Home = () => (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>
    )

    const About = ({ match }) => (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
        <h3>Match: {match.url}</h3>
      </div>
    )

    const Topics = ({ match }) => (
      <div>
        <h2>Topics</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
        <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
          <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        )}/>
      </div>
    )

    const Topic = ({ match }) => (
      <div>
        <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
        <h3>Match: {match.url}</h3>
      </div>
    )

    const AddressBar = () => (
      <Route render={({ location: { pathname }, match: {url}, goBack, goForward }) => (
        <div className="address-bar">
          <div>
            <button
              className="ab-button"
              onClick={goBack}
            >◀︎</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              className="ab-button"
              onClick={goForward}
            >▶</button>
          </div>
          <div className="url">URL: {pathname} Match: {url}</div>
        </div>

      )}/>
    )

    render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Click on the About link (Topics has the same issue): notice the AddressBar, which uses Route render, at the top always shows

```
> Match: /
```

while at the bottom of the screen the Component displays the correct match.url

`Match: /about`

What am I doing wrong? How do I get a valid match object into the AddressBar?

Here is the ugly hack I used for my specific route where I need to know the specific 'league' parameter.

```
let keys = []
let path = '/*/:league/:id';
if (this.path.split('/').length === 3)
  path = '/*/:league';
let re = pathToRegexp(path, keys);
const result = re.exec(this.path)
if (result && result[2])
  this.store.setLeague(result[2]);
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Yeah,  the work around for me is simple.  Where I need the route parameters I just parse the path myself.  pathToRegexp is already installed by the router.  I have code like the following.  This is specific to my routing, so its easy ... your mileage may be different.  I'll post a little code above

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you're looking to be able to use React Router's matching tools to pull paramaters out of a URL. This worked for me

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'

const match = matchPath('/users/123', {
  path: '/users/:id',
  exact: true,
  strict: false
})
```

Source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/matchPath.md

Comment: Hey Zeke that is not what I'm asking.  Look at the Codepen I posted above the link to it.  Click on 'About' or 'Topics'.  And look what is in the Address bar.  Line 66 (second line of the AddressBar func gets a url from the match object RR passes in.  Its rendered in line 80 and you can see in the Address bar it says 'Match:/'  which is wrong it should say 'Match:/about or 'Match:/topics'  depending on which you select

Answer (score 0):

I guess whenever you need to use match, you also need to combine it with pathname

example

```
var match = this.props.match;
<Link className = 'xxx' to = {{pathname:match.url + '/target'}}
```